# How to manage "automatic text color" in webView

Tags: android, android-webview

When we enter a text in TinyMCE, if the editor's background color is white, the text without attributed color is black and if you set the editor's background to black, the text is automatically white.

Is there a way to get the same behavior in a WebView?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mistaking two concepts. TinyMCE is an HTML Editor, what means that it is made using HTML technology. On the other hand, WebView is used to display websites. I think that what you want to do is create a web page where the text changes when the background changes, and then open this web page using WebView, but it must be done using HTML instead of WebView.

Comment: In fact I want that HTML text written in TinyMCE, stored as HTML content, be displayed correctly in a webView as HTML content as well. The problem is that if the writer changes the TinyMCE background in black, it automatically writes in white but when the content is stored and displayed in the webview, the text has no color defined and displayed in black by default and in that case, on a black background. So I just want to know if HTML could allow to 'guess' what text color to choose depending on the background color.